# Delete substrings in a string object, if those substrings match string in a list. Python

Tags: python, string, list, text, list-comprehension

I have a string object (type str) called 'corpus_jn'. It is a composed of about a hundred sentences. From this object, I'd like to delete substrings I have in a list called boilerplates. Ex:

```
boilerplates = ['Contact Number: 444-444-4444.', 'More information provided on request.']
corpus_jn = (corpus_jn.replace(sentence, '') for sentence in boilerplates)
```

The code executes, but when I try to print it, it outputs a generator object:

```
print(corpus_jn)

<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000000012552518>
```

How can I maintain or output my str object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace` does not modify the original string. You need to reassign to it for every sentence:

```
for sentence in boilerplates:
    corpus_jn = corpus_jn.replace(sentence, '')
```

Or you can use a regex:

```
import re
regex = '|'.join(map(re.escape, boilerplates))
corpus_jn = re.sub(regex, '', corpus_jn)
```

This will probably be more efficient since it iterates over the string only once.

---

Just to clarify: your original codes does not do any replacement at all. The argument to `str` is a generator expression which produces a `generator` object that does nothing until something iterates over it.

The call to `str` however does not iterate over it, it just transforms it into that `<generator object ...>` text.

Even if you consumed the generator properly using `''.join` or a list-comprehension you would not obtain what you expected:

```
>>> text = 'hello 123 hello bye'
>>> boilerplates = ['hello', 'bye']
>>> [text.replace(sentence, '') for sentence in boilerplates]
[' 123  bye', 'hello 123 hello ']
```

As you can see the first time the word `hello` is replaced from `text` but the second iteration is still done on the original value and hence you get a string with no `bye` but that still contains `hello`. To remove both you have to use the solutions above, you can't do that using a generator in that way.

Comment: These generators outputs are rather perplexing and admittedly very frustrating. But I understand they save a lot of space, so I have been trying to employ them as much as possible. I plan to spend a lot of time with these as I have millions, and possibly around a billion lines to work with, each with a hundred sentences or so. Thanks.

Comment: @spacedustpi That output is the generic result of the method `object.__repr__`. Basically when an object "does not know" how to print itself it simply prints that string that tells you the type and its `id`. A generator cannot do really anything else because it does not know what it really contains until it consumes itself, and you probably don't want to consume it to print it.

Comment: I have to admit, this topic is a little advanced for me right now, but why wouldn't I want it it want to consume itself? Because it will tie up resources? If I am not mistaken, I can often print generator objects with print(list(<generator_object>) or  print(tuple(<generator_object>)... are these cases of it consuming itself?

Comment: @spacedustpi What I mean is that it is expected that the expression `str(something)` does not have side effects. But a generator can only be consumed once so it would have side effects in that after that call the generator would be completely consumed. That's why you have to consume it explicitly if you want to print the contents. In the cases you have show the generator is being consumed by other functions. `tuple` and `list` iterate over it to accumulate the values.

Comment: Ah, so once that generator is used, say iterated over in a list comprehension, that generator is no longer usable for a similar purpose in another list comprehension or print command?

Comment: @spacedustpi Yes, generators are "one-off". Once you iterate over it, it's done. That is also what allows them to avoid consuming space... they literally do not contain anything until you try to fetch an element, that element is then computed and returned, it is not kept into memory.

Comment: So they are not just pointers. They are actually consuming space, until they are consumed?

Comment: @spacedustpi Consider `(time.time() for _ in range(100))`.Whenever you fetch an item `time.time()` si called and returned, so it returns the system time for the instance you fetch that item. There is no way to compute this beforehand since you don't know when that iteration will happen and after it happened there is no way to compute the same value again. The generator only keeps the state of the expression that defines it. In this case it will hold a reference to the iterator over `range(100)` .

Comment: Wow, intriguing if I am understanding this correctly. So it keeps the state of the expression that defines it. The generator object holds code which merely is a reference  to the expression. The expression will generate a list/tuple/str when the generator is invoked with something like 'print(list(<generator object variable>)'. The only space the generator object is taking up is the reference code it is holding. Is that right? Though, I don't understand why it is one-off. It's just a reference, why could it not be reused, it is not taking up much space.

Comment: #@spacedustpi Functions can depend on the system state which cannot be reproduced afterwards. So it's not just a matter of memory but infeasibility.

Comment: noted. Thanks for the explanations. Mind... blown. I'm looking forward to applying this to my large dataset. I guess generators are what sometimes are called programming tricks to get past a shortage of resources.